# 2.9 Model Not Attaching to Rig, Object Uses Mirror Modifier

Tags: rigging, armature, mirror-modifier

I've been at this all day and can't figure out the solution. I've cleared the parent `alt + p`, cleared the scale, removed doubles, and on and on. Nothing works. My model uses a mirror modifier. That might be the problem.  Download the file below. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: you need to unparent the armatures from the object, then parent the object to the rig called metarig. Then I don't know how rig is supposed to work with metarig...

Comment: @moonboots that didn't work. Thanks, though.

Comment: @moonboots *rig* is Rigify's generated rig, created from the *metarig*. The mesh needs to be parented to *rig* not to *metarig* to take full advantage of Rigify.

Comment: @Blunder oh ok my bad

Answer (score 2):

You parented the armatures to the mesh as children. That's not what you want.

The mesh needs to be parented to the armature called *rig* which was created from the *metarig*.

First, you need to clear the parent relationship. In *Object* mode, select the *rig* armature and clear its parent (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>). Do the same for the *metarig*.

Hide the *metarig* or move it to an archive collection. You just need it if you want to change and re-create the *rig* armature.

Then select the mesh (*infant_model*) and the *rig* armature. Make sure the order is correct and the *rig* is the active object (highlighted in light orange). Then use parent them <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> > *With Automatic Weights*.

Switch to *Pose* mode, and grab the IK controls (like *hand_ik.L*) to test the rig.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: this worked 100%, thanks a bunch for your help :)!